# No Knockout model binding on automatically filled inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a knockout model that is automatically created from a C#-ViewModel:

**ViewModels:**

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public ActualLocationModel Location { get; set; }
}

public class ActualLocationModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**search.js:**

```
function Search(model) {
    var self = this;
    self._model = model;
    ko.applyBindings(self._model, document.getElementById("searchForm"));
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {
        alert(self._model.ActualLocation.Address); // proof!
    });
}
```

**Search.cshtml:**

```
@model ViewModels.SearchModel

<div id="searchForm">
    <input data-bind="value: ActualLocation.Address" type="text">
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Find" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        window.search= new Search(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
    });
</script>
```

So, the databinding is working as expected as long as I enter the values by hand. But in my case **the values are filled automatically** by geolocation. In this case the binding doesn't do what it should be (output is always `null`). Is there a way to get the Knockout databinding working on automatic filled inputs?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Assuming that's the entirety of your Search.cshtml, I don't see an element called searchForm, so the ko.applyBindings statement should fail. Is there more?

Comment: Uups. I tried to keep the example as minimal as possible, so I missed to leave the `div` element. I updated my question, thanks for your hint.

Comment: Answer coming in just a moment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here are the relevant bits to get this working for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        window.search = new Search(JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'));
    });
</script>
```

Notice we're parsing the model which was converted to JSON so we can use the resulting Javascript object in our model. If you want to go straight from JSON to your model, consider the [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) library, though it is no longer actively maintained, I believe.

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input data-bind="value: Location.Address" type="text">            
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Find" />
</form>
```

Here, notice the change from `AdditionalLocation.Address` to just `Location.Address`.

```
function Search(model) {
    var self = this;
    self._model = model;
    ko.applyBindings(self._model, document.getElementById("searchForm"));

    $('#submitButton').click(function () {
        alert(self._model.Location.Address); // proof!
    });
}
```

Finally, we fix up the alert to reflect the shape of our data (`AdditionaLocation` to `Location`).

Using the above, everything works as expected for me.